# How to type pi symbol in swift playground. option + p is not working on my MacBookPro keyboard...?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, swift-playground

How to type pi symbol in swift playground. option + p is not working on my MacBookPro keyboard...?
On typing option + p, it is showing "," (comma) in the editor.

Comment: This is probably more suited to [apple.se] but you might want to check your keyboard settings. What input source are you using?

Comment: Make sure you set your keyboard to us-international

Answer (score 5):

Just switch your keyboard to "US" and try `Option + P`. It works for me, look:

[image]

Comment: I'm glad for you. Please upvote and accept the answer :)